# Convert pairwise data into prefmod-compliant column order

Tags: r, dplyr

The prefmod package wants pairwise comparisons in the form:

(AB)(AC)(BC)(AD)(BD)(CD)...etc.

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently transform a long-format data frame into this format. I.e.:

```
dat <- combn(c("A","B","C","D"),2) %>% t() %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% 
mutate(V3=round(runif(6)))
```

I want to transform that to a table of the form (for example)

```
   AB AC BC AD BD CD
V3 0  1  0  0  1  0
```

The main thing I'm struggling with is an idiom that orders the data correctly. If I could reorder the dataframe dat to look like, e.g.:

```
V1 V2 V3
A  B  0
A  C  1
B  C  0
A  D  0
B  D  1
C  D  0
```

...then I could just go

```
dat %>% unite("V1V2",c("V1","V2")) %>% 
column_to_rownames(var="V1V2") %>% t()
```

...but the place I'm stuck is that I can't figure out an idiom to reorder the rows of my dataframe in the way that prefmod wants. What exactly is the pattern (AB)(AC)(BC)(AD)(BD)(CD) and how can I programmatically generate that order?

Comment: `dat[order(dat$V2,dat$V1),]` ?

Comment: I did not find an order specification in the documentation, but is it maybe reverse ordering from the second variable backwards? Like all D, then all C, with first variable in corresponding order? Also, are these comparisons order-specific? If so, `combn` would be wrong here

Comment: so what exactly is your question?

Comment: `paste0("(",combn(c("A","B","C","D"),2,paste0,collapse=""),")",collapse="")`?? is that what you need or are you looking for `do.call(paste0,c("(",dat[-3],")",collapse=""))`?? or do you need it in a chain: `combn(c("A","B","C","D"),2) %>% t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(V3=round(runif(6)),s=paste0("(",invoke(paste0,.),")"))`?? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Ah, Moody_Mudskipper's answer is what I was looking for. Can't believe I couldn't figure that out...